# SetTextCallback does not import

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I'm trying to make a thread safe method for changing label texts in a Windows Form using c#. I adapted this slightly from code in an MSDN tutorial, but the my visual studio can't find the SetTextCallback class they use in the tutorial.

the error I'm getting is "The type or namespace 'SetTextCallback' could not be found"

```
    private void ChangeLabelText(Label label, string newText)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(ChangeLabelText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { newText });
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = newText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a delegate.  You just forgot to copy/paste it from [the tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).  Be sure to not skip tutorial steps.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize the tutorial but I cannot find it...

What they're using is just a normal delegate method:

```
public delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
```

**Read more about delegates:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

---

**EDIT:**

Found it. The `SetTextCallback` declaration is in the middle (which is the same as I wrote except for the `public`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx